# How to choose the best region Google Cloud based on the network infrastructure?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

[image]

What is the best region for my users? 
Region A is closer but there is no network path to it. Does region B is the best choice for me?

Edit:
This for voice over app.

The image source:
https://cloud.withgoogle.com/infrastructure/

Comment: 1) Network performance usually is not a critical issue. 2) There are many factors that affect network performance for users, most issues are outside your control. 3) Generally the closer the region is to the users the better. 4) Your question lacks focus on exactly what you need to deliver to customers. Does an extra 250 or 500 ms really make a difference to your users? This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow as you are asking for opinions and this is not a Stack Overflow programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [gcping](http://www.gcping.com/) helped in choosing the latency for my users.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the previous comment the closer the region to your users they will experience less latency, however they are certain factors that are outside of Google control such as the internet speed of your users.

Follow [GCP best practices](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/best-practices-compute-engine-region-selection) for region selection which is summarized in the following:

- Latency
- Pricing
- Colocation with other Google Cloud services
- Machine-type availability
- Resource quotas